# Problem extracting title of page scraping with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to learn how to use rvest in addition to Rstudio. But now I'm stuck trying to fetch a title of an article.

The specific article is: https://voxeu.org/article/design-choices-central-bank-digital-currency

I have tried using bot CSS selectors and XPath but none of them with any success. I have tried doing it on other webpages before without any issues so I'm getting quite frustrated with this one.

The structure of the element is:

```
    <h1 class="article-title">
    <p>
    Beyond imports: The supply chain effects of trade protection on export growth   </p>
    </h1>
```

So it looks like there is a newline after the `<p>` tag.

The code I use look like this:

```
sub_page <-  read_html("http://voxeu.org/article/design-choices-central-bank-digital-currency")

title <-  sub_page %>%
html_nodes(".article-title") %>%
html_text()
```

Which returns `[1] "\n                "`.

If for example, I want to grab the article-content of the page there no problem using `.article-content` as CSS selector, and then it gets the entire content. I have tried some of the various suggestions that SelectorGadget comes up with but with no luck. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I was thinking its content is generated by JS at first but it's not. I followed the nodes in R and didn't see the `<p>` tag under the `<h1>` tag. So it's kinda weird, maybe a bug in rvest. One solution that works is `title <- sub_page %>% html_node(xpath = "//meta[@name='twitter:title']") %>% html_attr("content")`.

Comment: @xwhitelight thank you so much for your input. At first, I also thought that it might be JS but no. It's quite peculiar - but thank you for your solution - it worked perfect!

Comment: You should add a git issue to `https://github.com/tidyverse/rvest/issues` for the developers to check. It prevents errors in the future.

Comment: I have done that now. Thanks again!